# File ended while scanning use of \frac [2]

Tags: errors

The equation I'm trying to write is as follows:
[image]

The Latex Code I've written is:

```
$\text{I.F.}= \frac{1}{Mk+Nt}= \frac{1}{k \sqrt{t^2+k^2}+kt-kt}= \frac{1}{k\sqrt{t^2+k^2}}$
```

I keep getting the aforementioned error. I've read the answers to an identical question and tried to remove any line from this equation. Still the error persists.

Comment: I used your code and it produces the output as desired. However, you can't use `$` in an `equation` environment (if this should be the case)

Comment: The error message shows that the bug is on line 1, whereas the equation is written 65. Why?

Comment: It got fixed. I forgot to use a bracket in a previous equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed `$` as `$$`, and used `amsmath` package:

Input:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
\text{I.F.}= \frac{1}{Mk+Nt}= \frac{1}{k \sqrt{t^2+k^2}+kt-kt}= \frac{1}{k\sqrt{t^2+k^2}}
$$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No, please! No! [**Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) Anyway, changing `$` to `$$` just displays the equation instead of typesetting it inline and cannot remove the cause for the error.

Comment: Shrey Aryan, confirmed the real problem was missed bracket on the previous equation...